# Android: Switch between keyboards (input methods)

Tags: android

I need to switch between different input methods from my service. If my service is an input method itself (InputMethodService) then I can switch to different input from it, but I can't return back afterwards. It seems like the system allows switching to other input methods only for currently active ones.

I have two third-party keyboards, not written by me and I need to switch between them. Do you have any idea on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this may be too late for your needs but someone has figured this out programmatically, at least for root users.

I use Tasker to automate stuff on my device and like many people I needed it to be able to directly switch between two input methods. XDA forum user intangibleDroid has written this plugin to do the job: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1217767